# Selenium c# how to get a window title by searching by its Handle Id?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

In order to get a browser window title, the web driver must switch to the window by its Handle id:

```
string title = driver.SwitchTo().Window("Handle ID").Title;
```

I am testing opening multiples windows and I need to get a window's title by only having the Handle Id and also without the web driver focusing the selected window bringing it to the front. This is what I have:

```
public string getWindowTitleByHandleId(string handleId){
    string[] handles = driver.WindowHandles.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < handles.Length; i++)
    {
        if (handles[i] == handleId) { return driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles[i]).Title}
    }
    return "";
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This question is really confusing.  Are you looking to get all of the window titles, just the current one...?  More clarification is needed here.

Comment: Done, sorry about that. I am trying to get only one window's title by searching by its Handle Id. Let's say I have 100 windows opened and I need to retrieve the title of window N° 37.

Comment: And are you getting any title at all, at this time?

Comment: Yes, but the driver focuses the window I am searching for. And I have to switch it back to where it left. Looks ugly and probably there is a better way to do it. Not to mention that maybe Selenium web driver have a method for this case.

Comment: Did you find a better way of doing this? I am using winappdriver and switching a window to find the title has the side effect of closing some of my windows that close when they loose focus, so having a way of enumerating them all without switching window would be very handy.